# How to keep a link tag a different color when on that page?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I want the tag of the page you are currently on to be in a different color than the rest of the links. For example:

My links are white, but on hover they change to red with an underline. I want the page you are on to always be red with the underline. How can I do this?

Comment: Add an `.active` class to the links with a specific style and apply them on the *active* page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate style for the active tabs. Give the tab that is now active that specific style (via a `class` or `id` in CSS)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like `.active` and apply it to the active page.

**HTML (example.com/activepage)**

```
<a href="#">Some Link</a>
<a href="example.com/activepage" class="active">Active Link</a>
<a href="#">Some Other Link</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a:hover {
  color: red;
}

a.active {
  color: green;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/aawDn/)**